# Bootstrap 4 navbar collapse hide open others

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I made a navbar that collapses in mobile view with 4 icons/buttons.

When I press one button it's expanding perfect, but when I press the second button the first stays expanded. I want to hide that so it only shows one expanded area (so in the picture hide "inloggen" when the uses presses search).

> [image: example of current result]

Here is the markup that shows what I currently have:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark justify-content-center navigatie-balk">
    <div class="container d-flex flex-wrap">
        <!--- logo --->
        <div class="justify-content-start" id="div-logo">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo $this->url('home'); ?>" target="_self">
                <img src="<?= $this->basePath('img/logo.png') ?>"/>
            </a>
        </div>
        <!-- buttons/hamburger menu -->
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#button1" style="margin-top: 12px;">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#div-zoeken" style="margin-top: 12px;">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" id="zoeken-toggle"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#inloggen" style="margin-top: 12px;">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" id="inloggen-toggle"></span>
            </button>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#plaatsen" style="margin-top: 12px;">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" id="plaatsen-toggle"></span>
            </button>                
        <!-- Zoeken -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="div-zoeken">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                    <div class="input-group" style="height: 30px;">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zoeken..." style="border: none;width: 250px;">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light" style="border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 0px;padding:0px 5px 3px 5px;height: 30px;"><img src="<?= $this->basePath('img/magnifying-glass-6x.png') ?>" style="height: 16px;"/></button>                
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
        <!--- plaatsen en inloggen -->
        <div class="flex-column justify-content-end" id="div-plaatsen">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light btn-primary btn-sm" id="advertentie-plaatsen" style="height: 25px; padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;">Advertentie plaatsen</button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="plaatsen" style="float: left;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="font-size: 14px;">
                    <li class="nav-item active" id="plaatsen-link">
                        <a class="nav-link"href="#"><img src="<?= $this->basePath('img/plaatsen-advertentie.png') ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;Advertentie plaatsen<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link"href="#"><img src="<?= $this->basePath('img/briefcase.png') ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;Bedrijfsvermelding<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>    
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="inloggen" style="float: right;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="font-size: 14px;">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="<?= $this->basePath('inloggen') ?>"><img src="<?= $this->basePath('img/person-2x.png') ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;Inloggen<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you're wondering where some of the down votes might come from: There was a spam answer posted and that got attention on Meta. There  was some discussion if the image you used was spamming the site. To counter that argument I blurred your url in the image as it didn't seem relevant for the issue at hand.  I'm not sure how hard this is but would you be able to adapt your code so it works in a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753)? I tried but then I realized I miss CSS and couldn't dream-up the images that are missing. Have a working demo might help potential answeresrs.

Comment: @rene I don't think the meta post is about this exact question. The meta is about a SPAM question offering loans. As a Dutch myself, I can tell you that the text in the image here is about finding houses that are open for rent or putting your own house up for rent. Nothing to do with loans at all. I checked the edit history and this question never contained anything related to loans. So I rly have no idea what happened here.

Comment: @icecub there is a deleted answer on this question that is spam (*Er is geen woord Frans bij*). I can't fix that people from meta end-up on the question where the issue only exists in the now deleted answer. I only wanted to prevent collateral damage.

Comment: I've edited the meta question as well to make 100% clear it is all about the (deleted) answer.

Comment: Dank je wel rene . Thanks rene. No spam intentions indeed! Now waiting for the answer, because i didnt figure it out yet...